# Member access into incomplete type

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

```
struct B;
struct A {
    void funcA(B &b) {
        b.funcB(*this);  // Here where is an error: Member access into incomplete type 'B'
    }
};
struct B {
    A a;
    void funcB(A a1) {
    }
};
```

As I understand, I need to somehow define B::funcB, because when I swap function body, the error occurs in the A struct.

Comment: What does [your favourite C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) say about splitting declaration and definition (or about header files and implementation files)?

Comment: I didn't read any programming books

Comment: Well, I suggest getting one. C++ is a difficult language to take up and without a good book you will struggle a lot with things like that.

Answer (score 3):

Define the function outside of the class body:

```
struct B;

struct A
{
    void funcA(B &b);
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    void funcB(A a1) {}
};

void A::funcA(B &b)
{
    b.funcB(*this);
}
```

Note that because `B` contains a member variable of type `A` (as opposed to e.g. `A *`), it's impossible to define `struct B` before `struct A`.

Comment: he can also have `struct B; void funcB (A a1);` on top.

Comment: @user5550963 He can't, because `B` has `A` as a member variable.